# Are ARP messages always used for the process of "Flooding" even when layer-3 is not involved?

Tags: mac-address, layer2, layer3

I'm new to learning networking so please bear with me.

I've learned that ARP messages and flooding are used to find mac addresses when IP addresses are involved.

I've learned that when the mac address of a destination device is not known that flooding is a tool that is used to find it.

So my question is: are ARP messages always used to find Mac Addresses of unknown destination devices irrespective of any layer-3 (IP address) involvement?

Put another way:

If we have a network of devices, and (hypothetically) none of them have IP addresses, are ARP messages used to find Mac addresses of destination device or is some other mechanism used for the "Flooding"?

Thank you.

Comment: ARP is used by IPv4 to resolve an IP address to its associated MAC address. You cannot use it for general discovery, especially not without a destination's IPv4 address.

Comment: ARP's are *broadcast*. Flooding refers to a switch sending a frame to every port because it doesn't have a known destination. Broadcasts go to every port, because they're broadcast. A *smart* switch *might* filter that ARP broadcast to only the port known to lead to that MAC, and/or IP. (Part of some system's arp inspection / security.)